# Populating data in Dropdown List in ASP.NET MVC Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, mobile

I am very new in jquery Mobile and also in asp.net MVC3.
I am doing a project a on jquery mobile with asp.net mvc 3.
I direly need to display data in  dropdown list.
Cant understand how to display dropdownlist & how to poupulate data in it.

Please give me some suggestions to get rid of this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery SelectBoxes](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/) Plugin..

```
$('#YourSelectListID').ajaxAddOption('/Controller/Action/', {}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to do somthing like  - user clicks the dropdown and  a list a account no will be shown in a list infront of the page. when user selects an account no then data related to that account no will be loaded in the page. and in that case another 2/3 drop down will be be loaded with similer way. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.